# How to render a partial inside ActiveAdmin edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How can I render a partial inside ActiveAdmin edit page?
Here is my code http://paste.ubuntu.com/1222340/
I want to render a page after the submit button.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   form do |f|
        f.inputs do
          f.input :name
        end
        f.actions
        f.form_buffers.last << f.template.render('shared/test')

      end
```